# How to change the placement of the Page bar from the bottom to the the top right of the screen?

Tags: kde, interface, okular

I need to place the page counter of Okular on the **top right** of the screen instead of being on the bottom.
I use Okular Version **22.12.1** and KDE Frameworks Version **5.103.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterall it is hard to change the placement to a specific region of the window what i ended up doing is setting a shortcut to show/hide the bar when i want to see the page count.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).